# Javascript Showing Image

Tags: javascript

Can someone please tell me how to display an image instead of this showing as text. I am using this part of a html table script. Thanks!

```
     cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode("<img src='menubar/ico_delete16.gif' width='16' height='16'>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the "createTextNode" with "innerHTML".

Answer (score 0):

The elegant way:

```
var imgEl = document.createElement("img");
imgEl.setAttribute("src", "menubar/ico_delete16.gif");
imgEl.setAttribute("width", 16);
imgEl.setAttribute("height", 16);

cell.appendChild(imgEl);
```

And the primitive way:

```
cell.innerHTML += "<img src='menubar/ico_delete16.gif' width='16' height='16'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just the another way of doing it.

```
var element1 = document.createElement("img");
element1.src= "menubar/ico_delete16.gif";
element1.width = 16;
element1.height = 16;
cell.appendChild(element1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It was answered by a poster who deleted his answer but was correct! Thank you!!

```
cell.innerHTML = "<img src='menubar/ico_delete16.gif' width='16' height='16'>";
```